# working on local drupal website

Tags: drupal, deployment

I have website on external server and local linux machine. 
I prefer working on local version, because it is faster.

After adding new modules, and changing DB content (for example adding node) I wish to upload these changes to external server.

But how to not loose DB changes (and site/files) added by real time users ?

I'm using drush rsync and sql-sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) module to create new exportable features for the external website and they will show as modules. For example you can create a feature which contains a new content type and a view. You can also export roles, fields etc.

Use [Strongarm](http://drupal.org/project/strongarm) module to export system variables and settings. You can export nodes and taxonomy terms by integrating them with features module with [UUID Features](http://drupal.org/project/uuid_features) module or [Default content](http://drupal.org/project/defaultcontent) module.

Comment: So, as I understand the Feature is a piece of data from DB exported to new module file. So instead of synchronizing DB between two hosts, on local host after I build new content (something which change DB tables and files) I export it to file being ordinary module. Then I install that module on server site. BTW I hope that documentation to FeaturesModule is not so complicated as long...